# How to add a view into a EditText in android?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, mms

This is an mms app.
i'm new here, so i can't upload a picture. i'm so sorry about that.

the question is :
when user attach a picture to send an mms, i must create a view in the `IputBox(EditText)` to show the image's info like size, type and so on.

So, How can I create a view in `EditText`?

I konw How to insert a image into a `EditText` by `ImageSpan`, but I don't know how to insert a view.

Thank u!!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a view inside the EditText, but you can create a hidden view in the layout XML and show it only when relevant, with the information you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this I think:

```
setText(CharSequence)
```

To set some text that appears within the EditText. Not used it myself however so can't say for certain it will work.

Got it from here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html